# position: fixed within a display: grid on Safari

Tags: css, css-position, mobile-safari, css-grid, display

I am not a web developer by trade, so I apologize in advance for whatever unorthodox stuff I may be doing (and I am interested in knowing more idiomatic ways to achieve my goals).

I am trying to make a layout for mobile screens where menus (nav and such) are laid as 100vw×100vh blocks that slide in and out of view depending on a checkbox; the method feels kind of hackish, but it works reasonably well and requires no JavaScript.

I have spent a few hours debugging a frustrating positioning bug that only happens with a specific browser; while I have found a workaround, I would like to know if this is a legitimate bug, or if I am hitting some sort of "undefined behaviour" territory and the browser is well within its rights to just do whatever.

Here is a simplified page, with the CSS I would *like* to use:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header.banner {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: red;
}

header.menu1 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: blue;
}

header.menu2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: yellow;
}

.togglable {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.togglable>input {
  /* In the actual page, I set the input's opacity to 0 and put an img
     * over it, hence the position: absolute. */
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.togglable>label {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.togglable>input:checked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 42;
}

.togglable>.woosh {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #dddd;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: translate(-100vw);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  z-index: 41;
}

.togglable>input:checked~.woosh {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner"></header>
<header class="menu1 togglable">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu1">
  <label for="menu1">Menu1</label>
  <div class="woosh">hi</div>
</header>
<header class="menu2 togglable">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu2">
  <label for="menu2">Menu2</label>
  <div class="woosh">hi</div>
</header>
<main>
  Main content.
</main>
```

Here is what this looks like:

[image: initial layout]

The user clicks on a checkbox; the `.woosh` sibling div slides in and the input moves to the top right corner:

[image: menu overlay]

The user clicks on the checkbox again; the div slides out. On the final version, the opacity of checkboxes is set to zero and images are positioned beneath them; everything's peachy.

Except… on Safari? When it is checked, the input moves in some seemingly random place, clearly *not* in the top right corner:

[image: safari glitch]

I have no clue what logic Safari follows here. Both Firefox (84) and Chromium (87) seem to do what I mean (at least on the mobile view simulator of their desktop version). This glitch happens on iOS 12.1.2; I'm not the owner of the device, so it's not my prerogative to try and upgrade the system.

The workaround I mentioned consists in removing `display: grid` in `.togglable`.  It takes a bit of duct tape to get things to look the same (more `position: absolute`, some `margin-left` and `min-height`; it gets worse if I want to e.g. make the button for the first menu smaller than for the second, right-align the `<input>`s while left-aligning the `<label>`s), but it sort of works.

I realize that JS could save me some pain; even without going there, maybe radio buttons would serve me better (since I would not have to move the `<input>`); even so, I figure either

- this is a Safari bug, or
- my understanding of CSS is dangerously wrong.

Whichever it is, I would love to understand what's going on.

Comment: `position: fixed;`, doesnt work within a grid. The issues is, that `position: fixed;` moves the element outside of the actual flow. You can only use `position: absolute;` or `position: sticky;` in that case.

Comment: @tacoshy: Mmm, I find this surprising; I see nothing on [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-position) nor on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values) suggesting that `position: fixed` is somehow incompatible with a parent `display: grid`. I *do* want my element moved out of the actual flow, so I don't see how that would be the issue?

Comment: @tacoshy: Have you looked at the third screenshot? My problem is that the element is *not* placed at the top right corner; if it were, I would have no problem. My apologies if I'm misreading you (I should edit my question to point out the issue more clearly, though).

Comment: I see that it is a pure safari issue. I suggested an edit of your question accordingly. However one thing to add

Comment: @tacoshy: Thanks! I've kept "grid" in the title and the tags, since the issue disappears if I use `flex` instead; as I said in my post, I'm not ruling out that what Safari does is "legal" yet because I don't know the CSS spec well enough to assert that this is a bug.